# @viewchild es 'undefined' cuando ejecuto Ionic Refresher

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Ionic y Angular, la cual dispone de 3 tabs. En el tab3 tengo un mapa (con Mapbox) el cual se muestra correctamente cuando actualizo el navegador, pero cuando ejecuto el 'refresher' de ionic no me muestra el mapa. Dejo mi código para una mejor comprensión:

**Tab3.page.html**
En esta página es donde introduzco mi componente .

```
<ion-header no-border>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            App
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <div style="margin: 10px"></div>

    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="12" size-lg="3" size-md="4" size-sm="6" size-xs="12">
                <div class="postfullmap">
                    <ion-item-sliding>
                        <app-fullmap></app-fullmap>
                    </ion-item-sliding>
                </div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</ion-header>

<ion-content color="light">

    <!-- Refresher -->
    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="reload($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>

    <!-- Posts -->
    <app-myposts [myposts]="posts"></app-myposts>

</ion-content>
```

**Tab3.page.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[] = [];
  enabled = true;

  constructor( private userService: UserService,
               private postsService: PostsService,
               private fullmap: FullmapComponent ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reload();
    this.postsService.newPost.subscribe( post => {
      this.posts.unshift( post );
    });
  }

  reload( event? ) {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.following( event, true );
      this.posts = [];
      this.enabled = true;
    }, 2000);
  }

  async following( event?, pull: boolean = false  ) {
    .....
    });
  }

}
```

**fullmap.component.html**

```
<div id='fullmap' #fullmap></div>
```

**fullmap.component.ts**

```
declare var mapboxgl: any;
let map;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fullmap',
  templateUrl: './fullmap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fullmap.component.scss'],
})
export class FullmapComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  private fullmap: ElementRef;

  // @ViewChild('fullmap', {static: false}) fullmap: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fullmap', {static: false}) set content(fullmap: ElementRef) {
    this.fullmap = fullmap;
  }

  constructor( ) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {

    setTimeout( () => {

      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mytoken';

      map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.fullmap.nativeElement,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/.....',
        center: [.....],
        zoom: [....],
        attributionControl: false
      });

    }, 2000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

The error that I'm getting when I do the refresh is the next:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at fullmap.component.ts:50
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650)
```

He intentado solucionarlo con 'ChangeDetectorEf' pero me dice 'Error injection...'; he cambiado la construcción del mapa al método 'onInit', a 'ngAfterViewInit', aumentando el 'setTimeout' y tampoco se construye el mapa. También he intentado generar un 'eventEmitter' desde el servicio que obtengo los posts pero no lo he realizado correctamente y tampoco sé si es la solución. En definitiva, este error me tiene un poco frustrado, se agradece que me ayuden. Gracias.